Finiteness of hitting 1 for asymmetric random walk using martingales - uniform integrability
In Williams book on probability with martingales, there is a nice example that uses the moment generating function of the simple random walk on the integers to eventually show that the hitting time of 1 has finite expectation. I want to understand what happens if the random walk is not symmetric.
The setup is as follows. Let $(X_n)_n$ be an iid sequence of Rademacher distributed r.v.s, i.e. $\mathbb P(X_n=+1)=p$, and $\mathbb P(X_n=-1)=1-p=:q$. Then define $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$ and assume $S_0=0$. Let $T:=\inf\{k\geq 0:S_k=1\}$, the hitting time of state one. In Williams it is shown that the hitting time is almost surely finite, if $p=1/2$. The result should hold for $p>1/2$, too. For $p<1/2$, I would assume that the time is no longer almost surely finite, as the random walk will on average go to minus infinity like $(p-q)n$.
In Williams, they define $M^t:=(M_n^t)_{n\geq1}$ with $M_n^t:=\exp(S_nt)/\phi_X(t)^n$, where $\phi_X$ is the moment generating function of $X_k$. Clearly this defines a martingale with respect to the canonical filtration generated by $(X_n)_n$. Now
$$\phi_X(t)=q\,e^{-t}+p\,e^{t}.$$
For $p=1/2$, this becomes the cosine hyperbolicus. Now, T is a stopping time and so for all $n$
$$\mathbb E[M_{T\wedge n}^t]=\mathbb E[\exp(t S_{T\wedge n})/\phi_X(t)^{T\wedge n}]=1.$$
Since $\exp(S_{T\wedge n}t)$ is bounded by $\exp(t)$, if $t>0$, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem, for which the result is
$$\mathbb E[M_{T}^t]=1=\mathbb E[\exp(t)/\phi_X(t)^{T}].$$
That means, $\mathbb E[\phi_X(t)^{-T}]=\exp(-t)$ for $t>0$.
Letting $t\rightarrow0$, i get for finite $T$
$$\lim_{t\searrow0}\phi_X(t)^{-T}=\Big(\frac
{1}{p+q}\Big)^T=1$$
I Williams, the next step is to compute the same limit, but for the case that $T$ is infinite. I am not sure how to do that. However, I would guess this limit is not 0, as in the $p=1/2$ case, but I don't see how to proceed.
Another approach to circumvent that is to make a substitution $z=1/\phi_X(t)$. I could not figure out the exact form of the inverse, but wolfram alpha was able to do that for given $p$. Assume, we can write the inverse function as $\psi(z)$. My numerical experiments lead me to the conjecture, that indeed for $G(z):=\mathbb E[z^T]=\exp(-\psi(z))$, we have
$$\lim_{z\nearrow0}G(z)=\begin{cases}1&p\geq1/2.\\ \frac{q}{p}&p<1/2.\end{cases}$$
That aligns very well with my intuition, as for $p<1/2$ we have $\mathbb P(T<\infty)=q/p<1$.
I just cannot figure out how to prove the part with the inverse. Also, since $M$ is a martingale, and for $p<1/2$ the expectation of the limit does not coincide with 1, does that mean that the martingale is not uniformly integrable for $p<1/2$?

Almost surely finite and finite expectation are very different properties - I am not getting the question

@Snoop, finite expectation of a random variable implies almost sure finiteness. The question is really how to prove that the probability generating function is less than one on the integers, as opposed to being one.

And a.s. finiteness obviously does not imply integrability... which is why they are very different. I believe you should clarify the question body.

I am talking about "uniform integrability" of the martingale. For a martingale, uniform integrability would imply the existence of a limit variable, that has the same expectation as $M_n$ for all n, in this case 1. That is clearly not the case here if p<1/2.

Integrability = finite expectation, of course. Uniform integrability is itself different from integrability. Is your question about $P(T<\infty)$ in the various cases of $p$? If so, this answer may be helpful to you.

When $0<p<1/2$ and $t>0$, $0<\phi_X(t)<1$ for small positive $t$. For such $t$, your argument runs into a problem because $\phi_X(t)^{-T}=+\infty$ on the event $\{T=\infty\}$.
But notice that $\phi_X(t)=1$ has two solutions, $t=0$ and $t=t_0>0$. From a plot of $\phi_X$ you see that $\phi_X(t)>1$ for $t>t_0$. For such a $t$ your argument now yields
$$
1=\Bbb E[\exp(t)\phi_X(t)^{-T}; T<\infty].
$$
In the limit as $t\downarrow t_0$ you get
$$
e^{-t_0} =\Bbb P[T<\infty].
$$
From $pe^{t_0}+qe^{-t_0} =1$ you get that $b:=e^{-t_0}$ is a solution of the quadratic $qb^2-b+p=0$.

Thanks for the answer, I get it now!
